# How to test statements which depends on specific PHP version with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I have a construct like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public function doFoo($value = '')
    {
        if (function_exists('foo'))
        {
            return foo($value);
        }
        // if php version does not support foo()
        // ...
    }
}
```

How can i test this code with PHPUnit to achieve a 100% code coverage if the existence of the function foo depends on the installed PHP version (for this example i assume that the function exists, otherwise a code coverage of 100% is impossible). Is there a way to disable/enable PHP functions at runtime?

Any ideas how to solve it?

**EDIT:**

i have found a solution: the Advanced PHP debugger / PECL extension provide a function *rename_function* for this purposes.

> bool rename_function ( string $original_name , string $new_name )
>
> > Renames a orig_name to new_name in the global function table. Useful for temporarily
> >     overriding built-in functions.

Comment: What version of PHP do You use? Is it 5.3 by any chance?

Comment: i use PHP 5.3.15. the concrete problem is, that i have implemented a PBKDF2 method for creating password hashs. now, i found out that with PHP >= 5.5.0 the function hash_pbkdf2 exists.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a simulation of `foo()` in your test method. Do something like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Your test method
 */
public function testSomething () {

    // if the function not exists, create a simulation
    if(!function_exists('foo')) {
        function foo() {
            return $aValue;
        }
    }

    // your test code ...
}
```

This works because a function may defined into another method or function. Although they are defined in the method they are globally available.

Using the pecl extension is not required. Further it potentially *pollutes* the test execution environment and at least adds unneeded requirements.

Furthermore **note** that PHPUnit as from version 3.6 supports the annotations `@codeCoverageIgnore`, `@codeCoverageIgnoreStart`, `@codeCoverageIgnoreEnd` to can be used to exclude classes, methods or parts of code from coverage analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in PHP 5.3 and higher You can override the behavior of any PHP function.

Look at this

```
namespace Test
{
    function function_exists($function)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var_dump(function_exists('var_dump')); // bool(false)
}
```

This is possible due to the PHP's [fallback mechanism](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php). In short, when it encounters a function it first checks if the function exists in the current namespace. If not, it falls back to the global namespace.